# Find the area enclosed by the curve $x=t-\sin t $, $y=1-\cos t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$

Tags: polar-coordinates

Find the area enclosed by the curve $x=t-\sin t $, $y=1-\cos t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ and the x-axis

Not sure how to execute. is it just that $.5\int_{0}^{2\pi}x^2+y^2$ ?

and not sure how to account for the x-axis limitation on the area

Comment: Not sure I understand, is this a parametric equation? Or are they two different functions life $f(t)$ and $g(t)$?

Comment: No! You need to use double integral.

Comment: You write a single integral, but it should probably be a double integral, and there is even do $\mathrm{d}x$ whatsoever.

Comment: ^explain double integral?^

Comment: Something is missing: $(x,y)$ define the support of a curve in $\mathbb R^2$; to compute the area enclosed by the curve you should specify "enclosed"! :-) $(x(0),y(0))$ is different from $(x(2\pi),y(2\pi))$.

Comment: woah i was only writing the problem how it was given. well it said $0 \le t \le 2\pi$ more specifically.

Comment: This is a standard application of Green's Theorem, turning the area integral into a line integral. But I'm guessing this is beyond where you are. It would help if you told us what course you're taking and what you know.

Comment: This is Calc 9C, don't recall doing double integrals ever.

Comment: Please be a bit more informative. What is Calc 9C about?

Answer (score 1):

So, not knowing your level and what you've tried, I'm going to offer this

**HINT:** You want the area under the curve and above the $x$-axis, so you want $\displaystyle\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} y\,dx$. Rewrite everything in terms of $t$, putting in $y=y(t)$, $dx = \dfrac{dx}{dt}dt$, and you should get a reasonably simple $t$ integral from $t=0$ to $t=2\pi$.

Answer (score -1):

Reparametrize on $x'$ and $y'$ with $x' = \frac{x}{\pi} - 1$ and $y' = \frac{y}{2}$. You'll get a much clearer drawing, and probably much better formulae. After that, multiply your result by $2\pi$ to account for the initial (linear) transformation.

Comment: I am arguably an expert and I am at a total loss to understand what you're talking about here. The OP is, I would guess, a student in a beginning integral calculus class.